# Collect Fourier series terms

Tags: coefficients

Is there a way to make mathematica automatically collect terms like $\mathrm{Cos}[n\ x]$ with $n=1,2,3...$?
I have a long expression coming out of a Fourier series where I see a lot of $Cos[x],Cos[2 x],Cos[3 x]$ and so on, but    `Simplify` is very inefficient. I would like mathematica to automatically collect all coefficients of the various Cos[n x] without having to do it manually for each one of them.

Comment: can you show your initial code, so we try to help!

Comment: Try `Collect[exp /. Cos[x n_.] -> x^n, x]/. x^n_. -> Cos[n x]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is this what you are asking?

```
exp=3Cos[x]+5Cos[2x]+12Cos[3x];

Coefficient[exp,Cos[x #]]&/@Range@3
```

> {3, 5, 12}

Comment: Yes, thanks this is it!

Comment: you are welcome!